# Make Projection on discriminator-value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, projection, nhibernate-projections

I have this NHibernate mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="ParentClass" table="myclass" abstract="true" >
    ...
    <discriminator column="mytype" type="string" />
    ...
    <subclass name="SubClass1" discriminator-value="Type1" />
    <subclass name="SubClass2" discriminator-value="Type2" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So how can I get Projection of discriminator-value like any property in my DAO when I filtering ParentClass objects?
Code in DAO:

```
...
  using (ISession session = NHibernateSession)
  {
      ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<ParentClass>("p")
      ...
      criteria.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
          .Projections.Property("p.Property1")
          .Projections.???  // something to get discriminator-value from myclass.mytype column
      ...
  }
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be the way **`"p.class"`**:

```
criteria.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.Property("p.Property1"))
    .Add(Projections.Property("p.class"))
    );
```

[17.1.4.1. Alias and property references](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-aliasreferences)

```
Description                 Syntax               Example
...
Discriminator of an entity  {[aliasname].class}  DISC as {item.class}
....
```

Comment: If that helped! great sir ;) Enjoy amazing NHibernate;)